# Как остортировать все файлы в папке по их типу?

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно, чтобы выводился топ 10 всех типов файлов в папке и её под папках которые чаще всего встречаются. Не получается использовать команду `file`, но возможно я делаю что-то не так.

Пример:
Если в папке лежит только файл скрипта на python, то вывод должен быть
"Python script, ASCII text executable: 1"

Благодарю за ответы!

Comment: Сделайте на питоне с помощью [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: Что такое тип файла? Как вы его определяете?